# MUI - How to use pseudo class in specific styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-selectors, styled-components

I'm new to whole react and MUI styled components. Right now I'm working on a grid and I would like to style all children of specific component. What I would like to do is a  `${Item1}:nth-child(3n-1)`, `${Item2}:nth-child(3n-1)`, `${Item3}:nth-child(3n-1)` but it does not work like this:

```
const Grid = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    padding: 0,
    display: 'grid',
    gap: 0,
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3,minmax(0,1fr))',
    `${Item1}:nth-child(3n-1)`: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightYellow'
    },
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3,minmax(0,1fr))',
    `${Item2}:nth-child(3n-1)`: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightGreen'
    },
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3,minmax(0,1fr))',
    `${Item3}:nth-child(3n-1)`: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightBlue'
    }
}

const Item1 = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    ...
}));

const Item2 = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    ...    
}));

const Item3 = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    ...
}));

<Grid>
    <Item1 />
    <Item2 />
    <Item3 />

    <Item1 />
    <Item2 />
    <Item3 />

    <Item1 />
    <Item2 />
    <Item3 />
<Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item` is the direct children of `Grid` so you can use `div > div` selector:

```
const Grid = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  ...,
  '& > :nth-child(3n-2)': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightYellow',
  },
  '& > :nth-child(3n-1)': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightGreen',
  },
  '& > :nth-child(3n)': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightBlue',
  },
}));
```

If you want to target a specific child, you can add a class name to identify it:

```
const Grid = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  ...,
  '& > .item1': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightYellow',
  },
  '& > .item2': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightGreen',
  },
  '& > .item3': {
    backgroundColor: 'lightBlue',
  },
}));
```

```
<Grid>
  <Item className="item1" />
  <Item className="item2" />
  <Item className="item3" />

  <Item className="item1" />
  <Item className="item2" />
  <Item className="item3" />

  <Item className="item1" />
  <Item className="item2" />
  <Item className="item3" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Ok and how do I set Item2 and Item3?

Comment: @Teamol you can use `& > :nth-child(3n - 1)` and `& > :nth-child(3n)` to select the 2nd and 3rd item in every row.

Comment: the class name `css-16kb41` is generated from emotion, if you want to target specific comp, add your custom class name like in my second approach.

Comment: Yeah you are right I did not see that, thank you.